# Why Lua creates table inside table in recursive function?

Tags: recursion, lua

I want to replace each value in the `table` to another value. My code:

```
function substitute_in_table(requests)
    local function helper(r, result)
        for k, v in pairs(r) do
            if type(v) == "table" then
                result[k] = helper(v, result)
            else
                result[k] = 'someValue'
            end
        end
        return result
    end

    return helper(requests, {})
end


r = {
    request = {
        headers = "a",
        body = "b"
    }
}
result = substitute_in_table(r)
print(inspect(result))
```

In the result I have got a table like this:

```
{
   headers = "someValue"
   body = "someValue",
   request = {
      headers = "someValue"
      body = "someValue"
   }
}
```

But the expected result is

```
request = {
    headers = "someValue"
    body = "someValue"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you should change line

```
result[k] = helper(v, result)
```

into

```
result[k] = helper(v, {})
```

so you would copy subtable into new table, and then insert result into original table, instead of copying subtable directly into original table